# Google Assistant sending incorrect input even though parsing correctly

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've been training my google assistant agent, and it looks like it is properly parsing the spoken text, but when I receive the input from my endpoint, it is incorrect. For example:

```
"resolvedQuery": "turn on climate control using pin one one one one",
"speech": "",
"action": "",
"actionIncomplete": false,
"parameters": {
    "vehicleName": "",
    "VEHICLE_NAME_NEXT": "",
    "PIN_NEXT": "using pin",
    "pin": "111",
    "temperature": "",
    "ENABLE": "enable",
    "CLIMATE_CONTROL": "climate control"
},
```

In the training data and in my intent, the "one one one one" is a number sequence and it recognizes it as a number sequence and it even says the value is "one one one one". But when I get it in my request, I get the above, which is the pin is "111". Below is the intent:

[image]

Enable contains synonyms for any words that could indicate enabling something.
Climate control - things such as temperature, climate, etc.
PIN_NEXT - common joining words for indicating the pin is next. Such as: with my pin, using my pin, my pin, etc.

When I check the training data, it actually parses it correctly and even shows the "RESOLVED VALUE" as "one one one one".

[image]

How do I tell the google agent to actually use the input it parsed in the training data?

The key issue, I believe that is different from my other question, is that the trainer highlights and labels the values correctly, the intent contains the utterance, yet it is still sending the incorrect value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Assistant training parse does not match data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500817/google-assistant-training-parse-does-not-match-data) (which is your own question, which you answered. either update that question to clarify or remove the answer. posting the question again is inappropriate)

Comment: The difference is subtle. The other questions was parsing it completely incorrectly. For example, cufewName = number 5. Here, it is parsing it correctly, but is sending the wrong data. pin = 111 instead of what it said it parsed, which was "one one one one". My apologies if they seem similar. Maybe they could from the root cause. It is just really hard to debug and was looking for whether some other people had experience something similar.

Comment: Can you also update the question to include a screen shot of the intent? (it is difficult to see if we can duplicate what you're saying without seeing what you think is supposed to be matched)

Comment: Good idea. I have added two pictures showing the intent and the captured training input.